# Windows 10 will not let me do anything to the system Path environment variable. Can't add, edit, or delete

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

When I try to do anything to the Path environment variable for system such as edit, add, or remove and entries I get "This environment variable is too large. This dialog allows setting values up to 2047 characters long."

I know this error message has been asked and answered before but my situation seems different. I can't do anything to the Path environment variable. I'm not at a point where I'm trying to add more. I'm trying to delete and it doesn't even let me do that.

Is there a work around for this?

The way I'm trying to edit this is the typical way

- I pull up `view advanced system settings` in the search menu
- clicking the 'advanced' tab
- In `System variables` I select `Path`
- I click `edit`
  At this point I cannot change anything. I cannot add, remove, or change any of the entries.

Comment: Are you an Admin User of the machine; that is, is the User Name you are logged in with an Admin User?

Comment: Thanks, but I just worked it out and answered my own question. I needed to delete a lot of lines and putting them in a new system variable ported into `Path`. Strange problem to have and figure out how to deal with. Having too many lines of text is like a problem computers might have had in the 70s. Not only does Bill Gates enslave the world with a medical hoax but he's responsible for this garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by deleting lots and lots of lines from the Path system environment variable. Deleting these lines allowed me to press okay without an error message.
I then made a new system environment variable called `Path2` and added `%Path2%` as an entry in `Path`.